# Проблема с глобальными переменными в content script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-extension

Аддон с помощью pageMod загружает content script xpath.js на открытую страницу:

```
//addon side
mod = PageMod({
    include: ['*'],
    contentScriptFile: data.url("./addonside/contentScript.js"),
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.on('message', function(message) {
            console.log('mouseclick: ' + message);
        });
    }
});
```

В скрипте определены глобальные переменные, которые используются для изменения атрибутов DOM элементов:

```
//content script
var oldAttribute;
var previousElem = null;
var previousElemAttr = null;
var allElems = []; // будет использован для подсветки дочерних элементов
```

Определены обработчики событий, в рамках которых меняются атрибуты DOM элементов:

```
//content script
window.addEventListener('click', clickListener, true);  //"true" kill button click
window.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseoverListener, true);
window.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseoutListener, true);
```

Внутри функций-обработчиков глобальные переменные всегда **доступны**.

От аддона в content script может быть отправлено сообщение:

```
//addon side
mod.port.emit("alert", messageFromAddon);
```

Но для обработчика этого сообщения глобальные переменные уже **НЕ** доступны:

```
//content script
self.port.on('alert', function(messageFromAddon){
    .....
    previousElem.setAttribute('style', previousElemAttr); // восстанавливаем исходные атрибуты кликнутому элементу
    .... 
});
```

При обработке события возникает следующая ошибка:

```
console.error: 
JPM [error]   Message: TypeError: previousElem is null
```

Самая большая странность заключается в том, что так происходит не всегда! Такая последовательность действий устраняет ошибку:

1. запуск firefox с помощю `jpm run -b /usr/bin/firefox`
2. загрузка content script с помощью pageMod
3. ввод URL в адресную строку браузера и открытие страницы

В этом случае `previousElem` уже не будет равен `null`, и работа с ним всегда **идёт нормально**, я могу получить доступ к атрибутам DOM элемента.

Хочется понять, что происходит и как это исправить?

лог:

```
console.error: 
JPM [error]   Message: TypeError: previousElem is null
  Stack:
    @resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://firetemplate/data/addonside/xpath.js:5:2
onEvent@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/content-worker.js:45:22
onEvent@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/content-worker.js:45:22
onChromeEvent@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/content-worker.js:91:16
```

**EDIT**
Простой пример для воспроизведения бага: [AddonForSO](https://github.com/AlexCAPS/AddonForSO)

Comment: Первое. Вы же сами указываете глобальную переменную как null: `var previousElem = null;`. Второе. Опишите последовательность действий при изменении кода в дополнении. Т.е. как Вы его запускаете в браузере обычно. И третье, в консоли браузера `Ctrl+J` есть ли ещё другие ошибки, связанные с данным дополнением?

Comment: Да, `previousElem` изначально инициализируя как null, но позже в ф-ии clickListener ей присваивается другое значение: `var elem = event.target; previousElem = elem;`
И между двумя разными кликами переменная `previousElem` содержит старый dom элемент

Comment: Аддон выполняет `mod.port.emit("alert", messageFromAddon);` только после того, как был загружен content script и только после того, как с помощью клика мышью был выбран какой-то dom элемент и была инициализированна переменная `previousElem`. Между разными кликами (и разными запусками обработки события `click` в функции `clickListener`) значение переменной  `previousElem` сохраняется

Comment: Принцип дополнения мне понятен. Ответьте на два вопроса: 1) как Вы разрабатывает дополнение, например, изменили код -> закрыли браузер -> запустили браузер -> запустили дополнение или как-то иначе? 2) Есть ли ещё ошибки у данного дополения в Browser Console?

Comment: Создаётся впечатление, что `window.addEventListener` и `self.port.on` работают с разными контекстами

Comment: @edem, теперь именно так. Изменил код, закрыл firefox, снова jpm run -b /usr/bin/firefox, снова открыл страницу, запустил плагин, проверил работу.

Comment: Больше ничего нет P.S. перед тем, как показать этот лог, был случайный успешный запуск

Comment: Дело не в контекстах, а скорее всего в том, что при изменении дополнения и при последующей работе с ним (т.е. когда браузер не перезапускается), используются обработчик, который ссылается на старый вариант глобальной переменной, которая естественно уже недоступна. Соответственно перезапуск браузера ставит всё на свои места.

Comment: @edem, но я перезапускаю браузер каждый раз

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41001/discussion-between-edem-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.activeTab.reload();

mod = pageMod.PageMod({...});
```

Перед загрузкой скрипта обновляю страницу. Не самый изящный, но рабочий способ.

**EDIT:**
Случайно удалось разобраться в причинах такого поведения.

Дело в том, что `include: ['*']` подключает скрипт ко всем страницам. Даже к той, которая в [dev/panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/dev_panel). Возникает ситуация, когда два слушателя обрабатывают одно и то же событие `alert`. `include: [getCurrentURL()]` устраняет эту проблему.